# problema con patron regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

Se deben permiten números de 4 o 6 dígitos y los números no pueden contener nada más que exactamente 4 dígitos o exactamente 6 dígitos.

Si a la función se le pasa una cadena de número válida, devuelve verdadero, de lo contrario devuelve falso.

para esto use este regex  `Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^\d{4}$|^\d{6}$");`

pero me falla cuando se ingresa "4334\n" (esto debe arrojar falso pero me arroja verdadero)

debo incluir algo como que excluya estos caracteres (\r\n?|\n)?

Comment: ¿Podría incluir un ejemplo de cómo está usando `rgx`?

Comment: Si esto es para un ejercicio, ok. Pero si es para otra cosa, no tiene mucho sentido hacer un regex para averiguar si un numero esta entre 1000 y 9999 o 100000 y 999999

Comment: @HernánAlarcón esta acá https://dotnetfiddle.net/icLlSt

Comment: @gbianchi se requiere regex, si es ejercicio

Comment: 4334\n tiene 4 dígitos, por eso te sale verdadero. Otra alternativa sin RegEx: Puedes comparar los `length` y verificar si todos `char IsDigit` y/o si pertenecen al rango > 999 && < 10000 (primer bloque de 4 dígitos solamente) y lo mismo aplicas para los 6 dígitos. ¿Por qué decidiste usar RegEx?

Comment: Sólo quería comentar que puedes simplificar un poco la expresión haciendo `^(\d{4}|\d{6})\z`. Otra opción: `^\d{4}(\d{2})?\z`. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esta expresión regular serviría al cambiar `$` por `\z`:

```
@"^\d{4}\z|^\d{6}\z"
```

`$` puede coincidir antes de un `\n` al final de una cadena según https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions:

> By default, the match must occur at the end of the string or before `\n` at the end of the string.

`\z` coincide solo con en final de la cadena según https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#end-of-string-only-z:

> The `\z` anchor specifies that a match must occur at the end of the input string.

Comment: Gracias hernan!! super y la referencia en microsoft ayudo a algo mas! gracias de nuevo